# jQuery selector from iframe to parent

Tags: jquery, iframe, jquery-selectors

I have a html document that has this structure:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrOq1.png <- sorry for link, but I can't place imeges inside question

I would like to get from my iframe to it inside parent document.

The simplest way would be to give my iframe id, but I can't do that.

In my iframe I have a selector like this:

```
$("table.TitleText > tbody > tr > td.TitleText",parent.document)
```

but it gives me two or three elements in my parent document.

I need to check if this td has text "MY NAME" in it, then do parent 9 times and then get next tr, then div with class 'contentNode' and iframe in it.

I know it sounds crazy, but I don't know how to do it another way :/

I need a selector that will find firsth iframe after TD containing "MY NAME", so I can change it height

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `closest()` method to get the `td` with `id` "title-bar" and its `parent` will give the `tr` which is at 9th parent level from the `td` containing "MY NAME"(which is what you are looking for). And then `next()` will give you the next `tr` and use `find()` method to get the `contentNode` within that `tr`.

```
$("table.TitleText td.TitleText:contains('MY NAME')")
.closest('#title-bar')
.parent()            //will give the tr
.next()              //will give next tr
.find('#contentNode')
```

Ideally ids should be uinique on the page in that case you can just use id selector to select `contentNode` div element.

```
$('#contentNode');
```

Comment: Thanks for help, I know that id's should be unique, but the page that has my iframe is generated by application, so I can't say it will have unique id's. Thanks again for help :)